# Why i get the "the connection was closed unexpectedly"-error in web request?

Tags: c#

I want post simple json to server with this code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ipaddress:1237");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{'params': {'auth_remoteaddr': '10.10.5.103', 'auth_type': 'ANONYMOUS', 'auth_name': 'ANONYMOUS', 'auth_pass': 'ANONYMOUS', 'login_auth_name': 'crm', 'login_auth_pass': 'crm1234', 'create_session': true, 'login_auth_type': 'ADMIN'}, 'method': 'login.login'}";
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

but when run that code,get the this error:

> Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: The
>   connection was closed unexpectedly.

but in the past that service succeeded without a problem, what happened? How can i solve that problem?

Comment: Maybe they needed a header, or the content type which you did not provide. This would be checked against the API providers and their documentation, we have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> This problem occurs when the server or another network device unexpectedly closes an existing Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) connection. This problem may occur when a time-out value on the server or on the network device is set too low. To resolve this problem, see resolutions A, D, E, F, and O. The problem can also occur if the server resets the connection unexpectedly, such as if an unhandled exception crashes the server process. Analyze the server logs to see if this may be the issue.

To resolve this problem, make sure that you are using the most recent version of the .NET Framework.